# Page-Router-Outlet inside Router-Outlet in NativeScript-Angular

Tags: routes, nativescript-angular

I want to achieve a simple app behaviour using NativeScript-Angular, which is to route to the main screens normally using a navigation bar, and inside a specific screen (with a ListView for example), route to a detail screen using Page-Router-Outlet, so I can have the History with Back Button Behaviour.

WhatsApp for instance has this behaviour, you access the list of contacts within the navigation bar, and go to a conversation via pagination. I tried to found on the internet a sample, but no success. Does anyone know how to do this?

My Code so far:

App.component with the navigation bar:

```
<ActionBar android:title="  Loteria Online"  android.icon="res://ic_launcher" android.iconVisibility="always"  >
    <NavigationButton icon="res://ic_arrow_back_black_24dp" (tap)="goBack()"></NavigationButton>
</ActionBar>
<StackLayout>
    <WrapLayout class="menu">
        <Label [text]="home" class="icon" [nsRouterLink]="['/']"></Label>
        <Label [text]="lotteries" class="icon" [nsRouterLink]="['/lotteries']"></Label>
        <Label [text]="user"  class="icon" [nsRouterLink]="['/login']"></Label>
    </WrapLayout>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</StackLayout>
```

Screen Lotteries with a button to route to a detail screen with pagination behaviour.

```
    <StackLayout class="page" >
   <Button text="Lottery Detail" [nsRouterLink]="['lottery-detail/1']" ></Button>
    <page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>
    </StackLayout>
```

app.routing.ts

```
export const routes = [
  {
    path: "lotteries", component: LotteriesComponent, children: [
      { path: "lottery-detail/:id", component: LotteryDetailComponent }
    ]
  }
];
```

The routing works, but not with pagination behaviour, just a normal redirection.